# Excel - rearrange rows with same columns value into columns in the same row

Tags: excel, vba

I have data from other software that outputs in the format shown attached. [This is what it initially looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3noc.png) I have removed data from all other columns that were not relevant to this task (i.e. columns A - H, J, K, M, N and P).

All items have different ID #s. However, each item has the same categories. Each category can have between 1 and 3 values, either numerical or alphabetical.

The actual data I'm working with has close to 500 items.

I'm looking for a way to rearrange the data so it [looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPVnL.png)

In response to a comment:

I want to do several things
 1. Move everything over to start at A1; in a separate sheet is good
 2. Rearrange data so the only columns are ID | CAT | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3
 3. Have each CAT only listed once for each item
 4. Move each Value with the same ID and CAT to be listed on one row

If any further elucidation is needed, please inform me.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a PivotChart on a separate sheet and filtering out the blanks?

Or, have you considered filtering the information?

I think we might need some more clarification -- from your message, it seems like you just want to create headers and delete the blank rows/columns.